# how to remove textbox outline in Opera

Tags: css, textbox, opera, outline

I tested the below code but gain no success:

[image]

```
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus {
    outline:none;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #B6B6B6;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #404040;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Is there something here I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera applies a yellow outline to form inputs that have saved login information. I don't think it is possible to override it with CSS.

Comment: Great, that was a login textbox. actually other texyboxes does not have problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using outline:none; try using border:0; given outline:none ll create cross-browser problem...

Comment: I use border to give style to my textbox, I can't remove it.

Comment: In which browser are u getting problem

Comment: As I said in the question title: Opera

Comment: did u try outline-style:none;

Answer (score 0):

add this in your css which u are using

```
textarea:focus {
 outline-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked with that addition on Opera/Safari/Chrome

```
input:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
}
```