# Different colors in box-shadows on different browsers?

Tags: cross-browser, browser, css

yesterday I recognized a small problem on my website. My Box-Shadows look different on most browsers. It used to be red (Firefox & IE) but on several it look totally different :

- Opera: Orange
- Chrome: Violet
- Safari: Blue

how can that happen ?

My CSS looks like :

```
input.test {
  ...
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
  ...
}

input.test:focus {
  ...
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(159, 48, 57, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(159, 48, 57, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(159, 48, 57, 0.6);
  ...
}
```

Could it be the transition I also use ? Or is it just normal that way ?

transition css :

```
input.test {
  ...
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.75s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.75s ease-in-out, color 0.75s ease-in-out, background 0.75s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.75s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.75s ease-in-out, color 0.75s ease-in-out, background 0.75s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.75s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.75s ease-in-out, color 0.75s ease-in-out, background 0.75s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.75s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.75s ease-in-out, color 0.75s ease-in-out, background 0.75s ease-in-out;
  ...
}
```

Hope someone can help me out. I truely want my box-shadow in the same color on each browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out :
Opera, Chrome and Safari (maybe even more) browser use automaticly outlines on form-elements:focus. So they can change the apperance of your boxshadow especially if you used opacity with it.

To get rid of those problems just use :

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
}
```

some similar problem occured here :
[how to remove textbox outline in Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327162/how-to-remove-textbox-outline-in-opera/24241440#24241440)

Comment: Note that it's generally a bad idea to specify outline: none due to accessibility reasons. Some folks seem to really need those. Also there's no need for zero in that.